# VBA Unique values

Tags: excel, vba, unique-values

I'm trying to find all unique values in column A copy the unique items to a collection and then paste the unique items to another sheet. The range will be dynamic. So far I've got the code below, it fails to copy the values to a collection and I know the issue is in defining the `aFirstArray` because the code worked fine in making a collection before I tried to make it dynamic.

What am I doing wrong in this because the items are not going to a collection, but the code just runs to end without looping.

```
Sub unique()

Dim arr As New Collection, a
Dim aFirstArray() As Variant
Dim i As Long

aFirstArray() = Array(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)))

On Error Resume Next
For Each a In aFirstArray
    arr.Add a, a
Next

For i = 1 To arr.Count
    Cells(i, 1) = arr(i)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `On Error Resume Next` to see what errors you are getting, and then deal with them accordingly. Personally, I prefer using Scripting Dictionaries instead of collections.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the arr.Add a, a which returns the run-time error 13: type mismatch. My data set is (column A) is numbers from A2 onwards, so i dont understand what the issue is.

Comment: This reference may help you in achieving your objective using dictionary approach. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482245/copy-unique-values-in-excel-vba>

Comment: The nice thing about Scripting Dictionaries is that they have a `.Exists` method.

Comment: @brax: You do not need neccessarily `.Exists` when adding an element to a dictionary, you can just write `dict(key)= value` and the key will be added in case it does not exist,see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/item-property-dictionary-object).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could fix the code like that

```
Sub unique()
    Dim arr As New Collection, a
    Dim aFirstArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    aFirstArray = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each a In aFirstArray
        arr.Add a, CStr(a)
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    For i = 1 To arr.Count
        Cells(i, 2) = arr(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

The reason for your code failing is that a key must be a unique string expression, see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/add-method-visual-basic-for-applications)

**Update**: This is how you could do it with a dictionary. You need to add the reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (Tools/References):

```
Sub uniqueA()
    Dim arr As New Dictionary, a
    Dim aFirstArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    aFirstArray = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    For Each a In aFirstArray
        arr(a) = a
    Next

    Range("B1").Resize(arr.Count) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr.Keys)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to be working now, so i interpret the Cstr turned it into a string so it can be saved.  Could you assist me in copying the values out from the object to another location? I don't know how to reference the keys we've added to the object.

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if this answers your question which it seems. Have look [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/) how to deal with collections. If you get stuck open a new question.

Comment: Ahh, sorry i marked it and thank you for the link! :)

Comment: Just a small comment, but your second range isnt fully qualified, refering to the activeworksheet.

Comment: Yes, right, I just copied the code from the OP and fixed the collection part resp. added a dictionary part. I did not fix resp. care about the ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative, without looping (allthough I do also like `Dictionary`):

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant

With Sheet1
    arr1 = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
    arr2 = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Value
    .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr1)).Value = arr1
End With

End Sub
```

You wouldn't even need to populate the second array, but you can do a direct value transfer to that other sheet your talking about. No need to populate any array/collection/dicitonary with Unique values, as long as you store the original ones.