# VBA Alternative for sumif/countif

Tags: excel, vba, count, sum

I have customer list and a list of invoices. I want to basically calculate a sumif customer name equals the invoice name. The data set can be rather large and there will be multiple sumif/countif procedures.

Is there a better way to do this rather than VBA "sumif", for example summing the values within a collection and priting it out? I already have the customers in a collection as per code below. What would be the most efficient way to do sumif/countif procedures for the following collection?

```
Sub UniqueCustomers()

Dim arr As New Collection, a
Dim LastLine As Integer
Dim aFirstArray As Variant
Dim i As Long
n = 1

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Select
aFirstArray = Worksheets("List").Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))

On Error Resume Next
For Each a In aFirstArray
    arr.Add CStr(a), CStr(a)
Next
On Error GoTo 0

Dim Customer As Variant
For Each Customer In arr
    Worksheets("Customers").Cells(n + 19, 5).Value = Customer
    Debug.Print Customer
    n = n + 1
Next Customer

End Sub
```

Comment: You could use a Scripting Dictionary for that...

Comment: So would you vision this as something like adding Keys from the above mentioned list to the dictionary. Then looping through a search range, updating the Key to the Key previously + new found value?

Comment: Yes, when adding the values, you can make them conditional on whatever you want, perform calculations before adding them to the existing.. instead of using a collection. I am not as familiar with collections, so maybe there is a way to do that with them as well. I just prefer dictionaries for various other reasons like quick key lookups when they are completed.

Comment: As you probably can imagine, im struggling with this. Is there a comprehensive blog/guide/code for this somewhere? Im not quite sure should i start by adding the unique customers to the dictionary as Key's and then starting to add items to those keys?

Comment: As in the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123467/vba-unique-values) I recommend to look [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) this time for dictionaries